# Spring-Data elastic search repo count with custom @Query annotation not working "Expected 1 but found 30 results"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

For my application I have to perform a custom count on elastic, I want to use the @Query annotation for this in the ElasticsearchCrudRepository we use. When I use the following signature:

```
@Query("CUSTOM BOOL QUERY HERE")
long countItemsCustom();
```

This leads to a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 1 but found 30 results` Exception since it is executed as an query instead of an count. For spring-data-cassandra we have a special @CountQuery annotation to solve this issue. Is there a similar solution in spring-data-elasticsearch ?

I could use the elastic client or template to perform a custom query and get the results, but I prefer using the existing repository interface for this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible at the moment. The `ElasticsearchStringQuery` class checks the return type of the method that is annotated with the `@Query` annotation and then executes the `ElasticsearchOperations.queryFor...()` method that is appropriate for the method's return type. These are queries for data and not for the count.

I created an issue in the [Spring Data Elasticsearch Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-584) to have this feature added.