# Can't count the occurences of the entity with a field of particular value inside a nested property using Spring Data ElasticSearch Repository

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the *Article* entity and inside it there is a nested property, let's say *Metadata*.

I need to count all articles, which have a particular field inside this nested property, let's say *indexed*, assigned to e.g. 1.

**Java Document Snippet:**

```
@Document(indexName = "article", type = "article", useServerConfiguration = true, createIndex = false)
@Setting(settingPath = "/mappings/settings.json")
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/articles.json")
public class Article {

// getters and setters, empty constructor are omitted for brevity
    @Id
    private String id;

    private Metadata metadata;

// remainder of the body is omitted

}
```

**Metadata.class snippet**

```
public class Metadata {

// getters and setters, empty constructor are omitted for brevity
    private Integer indexed;

// remainder of the body is omitted
}
```

**The query I use to retrieve articles, which satisfy the given criteria and which I put as a value of `@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query` on top of the custom method**:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "metadata.indexed": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**My custom Spring Data ElasticSearch repository snippet with a custom method:**

```
public CustomSpringDataElasticsearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Article, String> {

    @Query("The query from above")
    Long countByMetadata_Indexed(int value);
}
```

When I use the repository method shown above , I get [`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 1 but found n results`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259293/spring-data-elastic-search-repo-count-with-custom-query-annotation-not-working).

Custom Spring Data Elasticsearch Repository method(without @Query) returns **0**(version without underscore returns **0** as well) though it should return everything correctly.

How do I get the correct results using Spring Data ElasticSearch Repository? Why does the custom method without @Query doesn't work as well?

**UPD**: The version of *spring-data-elasticsearch* used is *3.1.1.RELEASE*.

Comment: can you share the code for the `Article`class and the complete code for the repositories - icluding the annotations?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am afraid that I can't share *Article* class completely but I am adding a snippet. What do you mean by the repositories? I have only one Spring Data Elastic Repository and it seems that other methods are insignificant, they are just your common Spring Data methods with supported keywords.

Comment: "When I try to use @org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query with correct query on top of the custom method," which query, which method? Without having more information, we won't be able to find where the problem is

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Oh, I see. So the value of  `@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Query`, which is placed on top of `Long countByMetadata_Indexed(int value)` is the query, mentioned in this very question as the one, which returns correct data for me.

Comment: that's not a count query, it will return n documents, and not one count

Comment: I see, so the query can't be assigned so the count query should work if being put as a value of the @Query? Could explain what are the possible reasons of incorrect execution of `Long countByMetadata_Indexed(int value)`?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I updated the body.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch could you kindly tell if you managed to find anything to troubleshoot my issue? As I far as I am concerned the query is incorrect, true, yet I'm not sure if there is an elasticsearch count query body at all.

Comment: There is a count API in Elasticsearch, but I'd rather not use that, because it does not use filters on a query. For a count you should use a query with max size set to 0, this will return the total_hits number but no documents. As for the query annotation on a repository method there is an issue (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-584). I think you will need to use the `Elasticsearch(Rest)Template` to do this query.

Comment: And there is no way to do this just with Spring Data ElasticSearch query methods without @Query as well, is that correct?

Comment: not with the repository methods at the moment (and not in 3.1.1), but you can do this using the `ElasticsearchOperations` bean

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I see, fair enough, appreciate the input. Please, consider summarizing this comment thread as the answer to the question itself and referring the question itself in [the issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-584).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository query methods currently(3.2.4.RELEASE) don't support the count by the fields inside nested fields.

[As was mentioned previously, `@Query` annotation doesn't support custom count queries as of the latest version(3.2.4.RELEASE)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56282838/8697659).

In other words, currently, the only way to do this query through Spring Data ElasticSearch is to use `ElasticsearchTemplate` bean or `ElasticsearchOperations` bean.

*Credit*: [P.J.Meisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393565/p-j-meisch)